# How do I place text in table with css and how to fix footer

Tags: php, css

What I want to do:

I want in each box, to be shown some data from database.
I've made a table which display it in 2 rows.. but I have some problems with CSS I guess.

My second problem is the footer. I want to make it so that it doesn't overlap the table when more results from the database are shown, but still don't know how.

I try with and without absolute position, etc but it's still mess.

## CSS

```
#infobox h1 {
  color: brown;

  left: 90px;
  top: 50px;
  font-size: 13px;
}

#infobox p {
  color: brown;

  left: 160px;
  top: 95px;
  font-size: 13px;
}
```

=====================================

## PHP

```
<table style ="position:absolute; left:0px">
    <tbody>
    <?php
    $i = 1;
    $columns = 2;
    $data1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `stuff` WHERE categorie='1' AND nr_redeems='0' ")  or die(mysql_error());
    while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($data1))
    {
        if($i == 1){ echo '<tr>'; }
        echo "<td id='infobox'>" . "<div class=''></div>" 
                    . "<img style='position:relative; top:0px; left:0px; width:423px; height:121px' src='../img/button.gif'>"
                    . "<h1>Some data about it.</h1>"
                    . "<p><b>Price:"
                    . $row1['nr_points']
                    . "points</b></p>" 
                    . "</td>";
        $i++;
        if($i == ($columns + 1)) { echo '</tr>'; $i = 1; }
    }
    ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

=====================================

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Danny. You might want to create a fiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/ for us so we can help you better. If your PHP code works fine, we will not need to see it, just use the relevant parts of code please.

Comment: I wasn't able to replicate that on jsfiddle but I got a solution for text and a temporary fix for footer..